# How to get data from cloud to android

Tags: android, list, cloud

I already through with the inserting the data from android to cloud and what i'm trying to do is, I want to get the data from the cloud which is stored (in my understanding)list the object "contains String datatype in cloud" and set it into the TextView 
here is my code:

```
package com.cloud.test;

import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.parse.FindCallback;
import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseQuery;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //id from the cloud and perfectly working
        Parse.initialize(this, "idp7tOItFQ1TeQ87NqG5okzgsTzBZSfOmTh3LjbJ", "sPlps2HcBLzfBcZTG8uUFPi5gHkGbwFYVGHhGtwd");


    }
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn1:
            /**
             * this is for inserting data to cloud
             */
            EditText et1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et1);
            EditText et2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et2);
            EditText et3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et3);
            String name = et1.getText().toString();
            int price = Integer.parseInt(et2.getText().toString());
            String desc = et3.getText().toString();
            ParseObject test = new ParseObject("Wardrobe");

            test.put("price", price);
            test.put("name", name);
            test.put("description", desc);
            test.saveInBackground();
            break;

        case R.id.btn2:
            /**
             * below is my problem, i don't know how do i actually get the data from the list
             * which is all String
             */
            ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("Wardrobe");
            query.whereEqualTo("description", "male");
            query.findInBackground(new FindCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(List<ParseObject> dataList, ParseException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                     if (e == null) {
                         TextView tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);
                         TextView tv2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv2);
                         TextView tv3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv3);
                            /**
                             * here i want to set the data to the TextView to be viewed by the user
                             */
                            Log.d("score", "Retrieved " + dataList.size() + " scores");
                        } else {
                            Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                        }
                }
            });
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for helping me

Here is an update i use `String.value(dataList);` and what i get is this `com.parse.ParseObject@44f904b8, com.parse.ParseObject@44f90a30`

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have an overridden toString method to print out something different, it prints out the class and what I think is the memory address or something like that. If you want to use String.value (or toString - same thing), you need to override the toString method of the ParseObject. If you don't want to, or don't have access to that code, you need to manually build the string you want from the getter methods provided by the ParseObject class.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void done(List<ParseObject> dataList, ParseException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                     if (e == null) {

                           TextView tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);
                        for(int x = 0; x < scoreList.size(); x++)
                        {
                         String d =  scoreList.get(x).getString("name");                         
                         tv1.setText(tv1.getText()+" "+d);
                        }
                            Log.d("score", "Retrieved " + dataList.size() + " scores");
                        } else {
                            Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                        }
                }
            });
```